# JRUBY JAVA HEAP SPACE out of memory error

Tags: java, memory, size, heap-memory, jruby

How can I adjust the Java heap memory?
I already tried

```
jruby -J-Xmn512m -J-Xms2048m -J-Xmx2048m -S rails s
```

but it didn't work

Comment: What exactly error are you getting?

Comment: Java::JavaLang::OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space:

Comment: Provide a larger value to -Xmx. If you're using more than 2GB of heap, then you need to allocate more heap, or change your code to use less RAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The memory argument should be like:

```
-Xms1024m - the init memory allocate when the JVM start
-Xmx2048m - the max memory that the JVM can allocate
```

Also use:

```
-XX:MaxNewSize - it could be 30% of the Xmx value:
```

`-XX:MaxNewSize` (in JDK1.3 and JDK1.4) or  `-Xmn` (new name of Young Generation flag from JDK1.4 onwards). Increasing the `-Xmn` (Young Generation Area) helps in scenarios where the Application creates short living objects (less caching Applications), because it increases the time of minor `GC`, most of the application objects dies early.

Note: you can put your won values.

Comment: try this `"jruby -xms1024m -xmx2048m -XX:MaxNewSize=512"`